# In "un dedalo di strade" si usa una figura retorica?

Tags: figures-of-speech

Quando dico

> un dedalo di strade

sto facendo riferimento al mitico ingegnere creatore del labirinto ma sto anche usando una figura retorica?.  Se sì, quale?

Comment: Se l'uso è inconsapevole, cioé non so nulla del signor Dedalo, ma uso una parola italiana che significa labirinto, sto  usando una figura retorica oppure no? Come parallelo: se uso la parola "psicologia" che deriva dal greco ma io non lo so, sto parlando greco?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[dèdalo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dedalo2/) s. m.

> [dal fr. dédale, che riproduce il nome di Dedalo, come mitico costruttore del labirinto di Creta].
>
> – Labirinto, ma solo in senso fig., andirivieni intricato di strade o di passaggi in cui sia facile perdere l’orientamento: cacciarsi in un d. di viuzze; anche in senso astratto: un d. di ipotesi, di considerazioni.

La figura retorica è quella della [metonimia.](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/metonimia/)

> che consiste nel sostituire una parola con un'altra che abbia con la prima una certa relazione, ad esempio di contiguità logica o materiale.

(Treccani.it)

Da [sapere.it:](http://www.sapere.it/sapere/strumenti/domande-risposte/di-tutto-un-po/dedalo-di-strade.html)

> ***Si utilizza dunque il termine dedalo per descrivere un labirinto di strade utilizzando l'artificio retorico della metonimia***, la figura retorica che consiste nel sostituire una parola con un'altra che abbia con la prima una certa relazione, ad esempio di contiguità logica o materiale.

Da [Wikipedia:](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedalo)

> In italiano viene utilizzato il sostantivo "dedalo" per indicare un intrico (solitamente di strette vie) simile ad un labirinto, ***derivando per metonimia il termine dal costruttore del labirinto.***

Comment: Ci vedrei bene anche l'antonomasia.

Comment: Tuttavia, se [dedalo](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI04/00000114.jpg) ha il significato di "labirinto, intrico di vie, di passaggi, di corridoi,  ecc.,  in  cui  si  perde  facil­mente il senso dell'orientamento", non sono del tutto sicura che si possa dire che si fa la sostituzione di un termine con un altro. Non è esattamente come quando si dice "ha un Picasso".

Comment: @Charo - la sostituzione avviene tra Dedalo Il costruttore e dedalo il labirinto sia in senso fisico  che figurato.

Comment: @Charo - Esempi: 
*Si hanno vari casi di sostituzioni metonimiche, tra le più frequenti il principio di relazione può essere in base a:* 
A) causa/effetto:
1) ascolto Mozart = la musica di Mozart;
2) ho comprato un Raffaello = un quadro di Raffaello.
3) ha una bella mano = una bella scrittura;
4) sentire le campane = i rintocchi delle campane;
5) avere le guance rigate di pianto = di lacrime;
6) "…s’accendon le finestre (le finestre sono illuminate) ad una ad una come tanti teatri…" (V. Cardarelli, Sera di Liguria, 5-6); - https://sites.google.com/site/mayersabella/letteratura-italiana

Comment: Sì, @Hachi, tutti questi esempi sono chiaramente metonimie. Ma, in questo caso, se veramente ci fosse tale sostituzione, si dovrebbe scrivere "un Dedalo di strade", no?
Personalmente, mi sembra semplicemente che il sostantivo comune italiano "dedalo" derivi dal nome proprio Dedalo (una cosa simile a quello che accade con "oceano"). Ma certamente non sono un'esperta nell'argomento.

Comment: @Charo -        In effetti si dice comunemente   un dedalo di strade, vie,  viuzze, sentieri, percorsi, etc. e ci sono  fonti che definiscono l’espressione metonimia.

Comment: @charo ha ragione Hachi, si tratta di metonimia (non antonomasia), in cui si sostituisce l'autore all'opera. L'opera di Dedalo, il labirinto, viene chiamato dedalo. E' come dire a un  pittore principiante, commentando il suo ultimo quadro, "hai fatto un picasso!"

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: La differenza che avverto io è che non si trova nei dizionari un nome comune "picasso" col significato di quadro o dipinto, usato in questo modo da più di un secolo fa. Ma non importa.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @egreg che c'è _anche_ un elemento antonomastico. In una metonimia pura diremmo “un Dedalo” per indicare un'opera di Dedalo, mentre qui ci riferiamo a qualsiasi struttura labirintica di cui quella di Dedalo rappresenta un caso esemplare.